# Why is thunderbird 115.4 signature is editable?

Tags: thunderbird, images, image-editing, lock, email-signature

I linked an image for a signature in my thunderbird. It works. However, whenever you go to write a new email, my signature image is displayed at the bottom of the email but the image is editable. For instance, you can click on the image and resize it. Why can't you lock signature? So, one can't edit it.

Comment: Why do you want to block yourself from editing your own email?

Comment: Are there actually any email clients where the signature _is not_ editable? (I mean, I can _kind of_ see the use case for Corporate Brand™ purposes, but even MS Outlook – the most corporate email app that exists – also works the same way.)

Comment: @harrymc Because the image has already been edited with image editor software to look how we want it to be. There is no need for the signature image to be edited further by the user.

Comment: "edited further by the user" - isn't you the user? And if somebody else is writing emails in your name, why would he change your image? Note also that you can control how the image is displayed on your side, but the receiver's email client may take some liberties in displaying it.

Comment: @harrymc I was referring to myself. lol as far as receiver, my signature image is recieved as an attachment and not displayed.

Comment: If you include the signature as an *image*, all the rules applying to an image apply to that. I.E., it can be edited by you, and can be copied, edited and used by someone else. An image is an image is an image, to paraphrase Gertie Stein. If you want the message to be immutable, make the **entire message** an image, with separately-sent checksum... one could *still* edit the image, but the checksum would not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, I do not believe there is any modern email client that *prevents* editing of a pre-defined signature.

In all modern email client software, signatures are a matter of convenience, not control. The idea is similar to a "quick part", perhaps, where you have pre-defined a collection of text, images, formats, and layouts, and this is added to every new email you create automatically. But it is only pasted into the email and then you proceed with filling out the rest of the email. Because it is pasted into a field where everything inside that field is considered to be editable, the signature bits will be editable too.

In other words, the reason it is editable is because the vast majority of people who use signatures in modern email clients either don't care, or actually want to be able to ad-hoc edit the signature *if* they need to.

As your question is "why", that is the answer.

In case you may have meant to ask "how", that depends. You would need some rule or function to act AFTER you have clicked the Send button on the email message, appending your signature as a suffix, not uneditable, but simply after the point in the process where edits occur. This could be a transport rule on your email server, or a macro in your application, if it supports that. What you could probably NOT do is set aside a section of the email window that is locked, because to do that you'd need to perform significant rewrites to the application code.